# Find Beanstalk VPC-ID via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I am struggling hard to find the VPC-ID for an Elastic Beanstalk created via eb create:

`aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --application-name myapplication`

I can fetch the Environment ID but found no command to fetch the VPC-ID for that environment.

**I would need a solution that is either able to:**

A. Tag the VPC on Beanstalk creation so i can find it by

`aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=myVPCTAG`

B. Find VPC-ID for the Beanstalk Environment ID

C. However goal is to get the VPC ID for a Beanstalk Environment, no matter how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following command which will print out the VPCId on condition that you've set your EB to be in a VPC:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-configuration-settings \
    --application-name myapplication\
    --environment-name <env-name> \
    --query "ConfigurationSettings[].OptionSettings[?OptionName=='VPCId'].Value" \
    --output text
```

If you created the EB environment without specifying VPC, the output will be empty, and it should be safe to assume that your EB is in a default VPC.